# How to override global before_script with empty before_script in job

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to override the global `before_script` with an empty `before_script` within a job?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Yes, the local `before_script` overrides the global `before_script`.
To keep the .yml sintax valid, use a command that does nothing.

```
before_script:
- global before script

job:
  before_script:
  - ''
```

Comment: How does one do the opposite? Not override the parent `before_script`?

Comment: @DavidCallanan you can either not declare `before_script` in your job to avoid overriding it or reference the global `before_script` to extend it in your job. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#reference-tags

Comment: To create a reference to the global `before_script`, enter this line into your local `before_script` as if it were a regular command: `- !reference [before_script]`. This way you can not override it but extend it with additional commands.

Comment: @jakub-kania solution is much "clearer" in my opinion

Comment: @gekkedev If your `before_script` is under `default`, you need `- !reference [default, before_script]`

Answer (score 79):

You should use an empty array notation.

```
before_script:
- global before script

job:
  before_script: []
  script:
  - test
```

Comment: This appears to simply run the global script instead.

Comment: @nCrazed You mean the global before_script? It really shouldn't. Please check if your pasted it correctly.

Comment: Yes, I mean the global before_script.

Comment: @nCrazed Please check the jobs in this project: https://gitlab.com/blckct/before_script , that project contains a demo and it appears to be working just like it should.

Comment: I've been testing it locally via `gitlab-runner` (11.3.1), could that explain the discrepancy in the behavior? :|

Comment: @nCrazed If you can confirm problem locally you should report it to Gitlab.

Comment: Works for me, and syntacticaly I like it better than assigning an empty string as in the accepted answer (which also works)

Comment: This GitLab documentation recommends using the square brackets notation `[]`. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#set-a-default-before_script-or-after_script-for-all-jobs